# supervisorctl could not start logstash

Tags: linux, logstash, supervisord

Logstash could not start under supervisord, but could run using command directly.

Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10,  logstash-6.5.3,  supervisord 3.2.0,  jdk1.8.0_191

If I start logstash with command `/usr/src/logstash-6.5.3/bin/logstash -f ../test/`, it succeed. But it couldn't run under supervisorctl. I have set java path on `/etc/profie`, and `java -version` could get the correct info. Could anyone give some help?

[image: java version]

[image: supervisor conf]

[image: superctl start logstash error log]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the reason, because I started supervisord in `service supervisor start`. This method upstart job in as predictable an environment as possible, remove most environment variables. If I changed to `supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`, it worked with the `/etc/profile` that export JAVA_HOME and ${JAVA_HOME}/bin, it did not report `could not find java` error log. So this command `supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` works.